# Capistrano - making sure that repository is accessible by my server

Tags: svn, deployment, tortoisesvn, capistrano

I'm going through tutorial to set up my [deployment using Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-from-the-beginning).  One of the steps is:

> we need to tell Capistrano where our source code resides. This is the
>   repository address for your application, and by default it must be
>   accessible both by your local machine (where you will be deploying
>   from) and your production servers (where you will be deploying to).

My repository is hosted on http://beanstalkapp.com/  and I access it through Tortoise SVN from my local machine. So I guess that means that repository is accessible by my local machine.  However, I'm confused on how to make sure that my production server has access to that repository?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to configure your production machine with SVN credentials (and obviously svn package) to checkout from your SVN repo, no matter where it's hosted.

Answer (score 0):

"To be able to deploy, your server needs to be able to access your repos" - https://help.github.com/articles/deploying-with-capistrano

How to connect to repositories - https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys

Also helps to understand ssh agent forwarding - http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html